# end-to-end alternatives

Tags: phrases, synonyms

I just received an email that included the phrase

> soup-to-nuts

meaning "end-to-end." Are there any other alternatives to this? eg cradle-to-grave? I want to include some in the reply email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to include a similar phrase in your reply email just for fun, you can use the following Latin phrase:

[*ab ovo usque ad mala*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_phrases%3a_A#Ab_ovo_usque_ad_mala)

It's basically the same thing as soup-to-nuts, except that it literally translates to "from the egg to the apples". This was the typical main meal in ancient Rome, where the phrase was created.

Answer (score 4):

How about *from A to Z*?

Answer (score 4):

From alpha to omega

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

from start to finish

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered "Womb to Tomb".

Comment: this is a good alternative

Answer (score 1):

I guess this one could be added to the list:

**From stem to stern.**

Answer (score 1):

Bust (as in breastfeeding) to dust!

Answer (score 1):

> ***from top to bottom***:
>     [the Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/from-top-to-bottom):
>
>     completely:
>     *They cleaned the house from top to bottom.*
>
> The [Oxford English Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/from_top_to_bottom) and [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/from-top-to-bottom)
>   give very similar definitions.
>
> ***from head to toe***:
>     [the Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/from-head-to-toe):
>
>     completely:
>     *She was dressed in red from head to toe.*
>
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/from%20head%20to%20foot/toe) and [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/from-head-to-toe)
>   give very similar definitions.

If you’re willing to go obscure,
you could use ***cap–a–pie*** or ***cap–à–pie***,
which, according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cap%E2%80%93a%E2%80%93pie),
is derived from Middle French *(de) cap a pé* for “from head to foot”,
and [rhymes with such words as “day,” “ray” and “way”](http://rhymes.merriam.com/r/cap-a-pie). 
[Shakespeare used](http://www.shakespeareswords.com/Glossary.aspx?Ref=cap-a-pe,%20cap-a-pie) a couple of variations of this:

> [Ham I.ii.200](http://www.shakespeareswords.com/Plays.aspx?Ac=1&SC=2&IdPlay=2#115346)
>
>   [Horatio to Hamlet,
>   <sub>of the Ghost</sub>
>   ] 
>     a figure like your father, / Armed at point exactly, cap-a-pe
>   [reading of F Cap a Pe; Q1, Q2 Capapea]
>
> [WT IV.iv.731](http://www.shakespeareswords.com/Plays.aspx?Ac=4&SC=4&IdPlay=35#243865)
>
>   [Autolycus to Shepherd] I am courtier cap-a-pie
>
> <sup>— from [Shakespeare's Words | Glossary, http://www.shakespeareswords.com/Glossary.aspx](http://www.shakespeareswords.com/Glossary.aspx?Ref=cap-a-pe,%20cap-a-pie)</sup>

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/capape) lists ***capape*** as an obsolete variant of *cap-a-pie*.