# Is there an expression for creating something from start to finish (e.g. grain to bread)

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

Maybe this is not really the right place to ask this, I hope I will not be penalized for asking this.

I am a webdeveloper, and I do most of the stuff myself, from the basic idea, till the final design and implementation. It's like when a baker has his own farm with grain, creates his own wheat, makes the bread, and sells it in his own shop.

Some time ago I heard a nice English expression for this, but I forgot what it was. It was something like *producing from grain to bread*. Does anyone know this expression, or can think of something that would nicely fit.

Edit: Roughly 9 years later we basically have a term for this. Currently I define myself as a Full Stack Web Developer.

Comment: Related: [end-to-end alternatives](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4884/end-to-end-alternatives)

Comment: I have looked at the related question, and even added one alternative to the list. There is still one that I have heard from my teacher that I still haven't seen. I will ask him when the vacation is over.

Comment: "Whole lifecycle" is the phrase I'm familiar with for involvement with a project from concept to maintenance.

Comment: @peter yes this comes the closest to the expression I am looking for I guess and I can surely use it. Still not exactly what I am looking for, it was is the form of _from ... to ..._. Another one i've found is: **from crop to cup**. A company that sells coffee in their store from the coffee beans they grow themself.

Comment: You've already accepted an answer, but _from inception to completion_ might have fit as well. (Although _end to end_ is what came to mind first...)

Comment: thanks, it's a good one. And even though I have accepted an answer,  I am still interested in more alternatives. You can always add more to the list.

Comment: BTW: Lerner Publications Company (www.lernerbooks.com) has a large collection of easy readers for young children on the theme of “Discover how one thing becomes another - from Start to Finish” - e.g., From Cane to Sugar, From Cement to Bridge, From Clay to Bricks, From Cloth to American Flag, From Cocoa Bean to Chocolate, and dozens more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something I hear quite commonly is "end to end", although this originally had a [somewhat different meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-to-end_principle).

Comment: Voted up after reading the OQ's comment on JSBᾶngs' answer. Given that extra info, I think this is probably the phrase to use.

Answer (score 11):

I believe the idiom you are looking for is ["soup to nuts"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soup_to_nuts):

> "Soup to nuts" is an American English idiom conveying the meaning of "from beginning to end". It is derived from the description of a full course dinner,

There's also "From start to finish", which is pretty clear.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this comes somewhat close to what I mean. It is not the exact expression I am looking for, but it's worth considering using for me.

Answer (score 5):

Something which is made ony from basic ingredients is often said to be made *[from scratch](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/from_scratch)*.

Ironically, however, making bread from scratch usually means starting from flour, rather than grain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is not really what I was looking for. I know this expression and use it often, but the one I am looking for goes beyond building from scratch, it's about making the scratch also. Just as you say, making bread from scratch is using flour, the expression I am looking for covers the making of the flour itself.

Comment: I guess the expression I am looking for is a bit off-topic for this forum. My question is not really about the English language, it's more a phrase that is used in production environments, sorry for that.

Comment: On a side note, check out [the toaster project](http://www.thetoasterproject.org/), this takes the definition of "from scratch" to its ultimate extreme.

Answer (score 5):

I can't tell if you're looking for a general phrase (like the answer proposed by @Gnawme) or a domain-specific one like your grain/bread analogy.  One I have heard in arts-and-crafts contexts is "from sheep to shawl", which seems analogous to your "grain to bread".  There are other domain-specific ones; many of them use alliteration.

Comment: +1 Good one. I am not really looking for a domain specific one. I was just looking for the one that I had heard before. But in this posts I have seen so many nice ones that can be used. Ill add yours to the list.

Answer (score 3):

A phrase used in the local food systems movement is 'from farm to table' or 'from farm to fork'

Comment: Good one, very visual and easy to understand. Just thought of a variation to this one: From stable to table. Good slogans for farmers etc. Will remember.

Answer (score 2):

2 more to add to the list: From a whole cloth, and Greenfield. From a whole cloth refers to something that is not modified from an existing kernel, but is rather new in all its parts. Greenfield (or Green Field) often refers to a manufacturing facility, which is created from the ground up (starting with a green field) as opposed to repurposing an existing facility. These probably don't quite fit your question, but I'm hoping they will trigger others peoples memories. :)

Comment: +1 This is a nice one to add to the list. Thank

Answer (score 2):

From seeing one of the OP's comments, and at his urging: *From inception to completion.*

Answer (score 2):

'From concept to completion' works well for me as I project manage retail shop fit-outs from design, then from the empty concrete box to opening day. Same as you really, just you're online while I'm bricks and mortar.

Answer (score 1):

cradle to grave
"from cradle to the grave"

birth to death

concept to completion

Comment: Cradle to grave tends to refer to the _life_ of a thing, rather than the construction of it. For example you could perhaps talk about the 'from cradle to grave' of a house, but you'd be meaning the entire lifespan of the house until it fell down.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard "[from Alpha to Omega](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/alpha-omega)" as well. This is also a biblical reference.

Comment: This is a nice one indeed Saqib. Check my edit in the original question.

Comment: Oh yeah. I am a full stack developer as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the idiomatic *from the ground up*.

> [from the ground up](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/from+the+ground+up): gradually from the most elementary level to the highest level : *She created her business [from the ground up](http://www.rongeorgejewelers.com/custom/)*.

Answer (score 0):

"From A to Z" might fit the bill