# Is it correct to say "from conceptualization to realisation"?

Tags: grammar, business-language

I am writing a business email to a client and I want to tell him that we have developed many softwares from first step (from an idea) to last step (a real product). Is it correct to write it like following:

> We have worked on a number of mobile applications from conceptualisation to realisation as per the client's needs and have a competent team of developers working in these technologies.

Please comment on grammatical and real sense of the sentence, is it good for business communication or not.

Thanks
Sam

Comment: Why use conceptualisation when concept will do?

Comment: "... from concept to realisation/reality to meet the client's needs..."

Comment: @mikeagg I wanted to emphasise on the fact that we developed the raw idea into a concept.. like conceptualisation being the first step of development and realisation or reification being the last..  in other words, I want to tell the client that we did everything from designing to development of the app

Comment: You might view the answers [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37686/is-there-an-expression-for-creating-something-from-start-to-finish-e-g-grain-t). It was a similar (though not exact) question.

Comment: @VampDuc Thanks! "Soup to nuts" is exactly what I needed. I am just not sure if it is suitable for a formal business email.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is a proofreading question, and not kosher, but here goes --

*Conceptualization* is fine.  *Realisation* is okay too, but see how you like this:

> We have worked on a number of mobile applications, from conceptualisation to implementation and client customisation.

Watch out with *these technologies* -- it's not clear what you're referring to.